# Edit Blender UI element

Tags: interface

how can i edit blender UI elements?
for example i want to change size of this button:

[image]

is it possible to do that? we can define or change UI's color easily by edit **xml** files. is there any way to change element's properties ???

Answer (score 2):

The size of the icons is hardcoded in the c files to 16 pixels. You cannot resize it.

What you can do is to change is the DPI settings in the User Preferences in the System tab to have the whole UI in a dpi size that fits your needs. It's the first entry up left.

Comment: i don't want to change icon size !!!!!!! i want to change defined size for buttons .... where is the code ? do you know ?

Comment: Also the size of the buttons is hardcoded, sorry. It all goes hand in hand. There is really not this much that you could customize here without to rewrite the Blender source code. Most of what you can do with Python regarding the UI is covered here: https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Py/Scripts/Cookbook/Code_snippets/Interface